# How to check two conditions with jQuery .not() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="content-part selected"  id="importantz" number="0"></div>
    <div class="content-part" id="internationalz" number="1"></div>
    <div class="content-part" id="businessz" number="2"></div>
</div>
```

I want get elements in $('#fullpage') that isn't in 2 group :

**1-** elements that have **class = selected**

**2-** elements that have **number = 1**

I use this jQuery code but not working XD.... please guide me:

```
pervSt = $('#fullpage').find('.selected');
sss = $('#fullpage').children('[number=1]');


$('#fullpage .content-part').not(pervSt,sss).each(function(){
    /* ahhhhhhh this not working XD */      
    console.log($(this).attr('number'))
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('#fullpage .content-part:not(.selected):not([number="1"])').each(function() {
    ...
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m95T7/)

Comment: Nice, didn't see you already answered it the way I did. I had not refreshed the page and missed your answer. In that case I delete mine and +1 yours instead. As an additional note to OP why this is a better solution then the original variables used in the question is that querying for all elements which are selected and all elements which have a `[number=1]` attribute only to exclude them is unnecessary overhead which can be avoided by adding the condition within the actual selector as this answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ZySYp/1)</kbd>

```
$('#fullpage .content-part').not('.selected, [number=1]').each(function () {  });
```

---

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ZySYp/)</kbd>

```
$('#fullpage .content-part').not('.selected').not('[number=1]').each(function () { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('#fullpage .content-part').not('.selected, [number=1]').each(function(){...});
```

Or using variables:

```
$('#fullpage .content-part').not(pervSt.add(sss)).each(function(){...});
```